# Calculate module of index int Struts2 iterator

Tags: module, struts2, iterator

I'm using Struts2 iterator to setup a list of checkbox in a table. I want to have 10 checkbox per row, so I'm doing the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <s:iterator value="securityMasterFields" status="fieldNameStatus" var="fieldName">
        <s:if test="#fieldNameStatus.index % 10 ==0">
                </tr><tr>
        </s:if>
        <td>
            <s:checkbox name="fieldsToShow" fieldValue="%{fieldName}" value="%{fieldName}"/>
        </td>
    </s:iterator>       
    </tr>
</table>
```

It never goes through the if, so I'm assuming the mod is not been calculated correctly. How do I do it?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Well, I had to add some parentheses and it worked correctly. The loop was working, it was just that it wasn't going through the if.

```
<s:if test="(#fieldNameStatus.index % 8 )==0"></tr><tr></s:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks good to me.  Two thoughts:

1) try printing the result of the test in s:property tag

2) It looks like you will have empty table rows... Are you looking at the generated html or just the output, because if it is just the output then unless you have some CSS giving you some table padding and borders, without an empty 'td' element the row might collapse and make it appear as if nothing is being added.  So do make sure you print the empty 'td' elements too!

Comment: The loop was working, the only issue was with the module to finnish the row and start a new one, but I got it fixed using parentheses. Thanks in any case.